# Dictionary for holding key value pair in gnome

Tags: gtk, gnome

Is there a class for holding key value pair in gnome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is [GHashTable](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html). However, note that the basic data types are provided by GLib, which GTK+ uses. Here are the [data types provided by GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-data-types.html) and the full [GLib documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/index.html).